# Can't open video using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, codec

The opencv works fine when doing other things. It can open images and show images. But it can't open a video.

The code I'm using to open a video is as below

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("MOV_0006.mp4")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when executing, it outputs error messages like below

```
[h264 @ 0x1053ba0] AVC: nal size 554779904
[h264 @ 0x1053ba0] AVC: nal size 554779904
[h264 @ 0x1053ba0] no frame!
```

My `vlc` and `mplayer` can play this video, but the opencv can't.

I have installed `x264` and `libx264-142` codec package. (using `sudo apt-get install`)

My version of ubuntu is `14.04 trusty`.

I'm not sure is it a codec problem or not?

I have rebuilt opencv either with `WITH_UNICAP=ON` or with `WITH_UNICAP=OFF`, but it doesn't affect the problem at all. The error messages never change.

Comment: did you try to open it with ffmpeg (opencv "wraps" ffmpeg...) ?

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: Also, did you run the tests post build?

Comment: did you try to skip a frame that could not be read and try the next one?

Comment: @xiawi What do you mean by that? How to do that?

Comment: @bad_keypoints I am using `opencv 2.4.8`. The codec it uses seems like this: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/3rdparty/lib/libavcodec.a

Comment: @bad_keypoints I've tried a few tests under `opencv/samples/c` and `opencv/samples/python`. Module `delaunay` works fine. But `facedetect` a video doesn't work.

Comment: @Micka I tried. It shows that it really can't read any frame. Every frame `cap.read()` returns is `None`.

Comment: @JennyaChang and why doesn't it work? What errors did it show? Perhaps something related to libav ?

Comment: @bad_keypoints It shows the same error message `[h264 @ 0xd04ca0] AVC: nal size 554779904` `[h264 @ 0xd04ca0] no frame!` Just these. And then the program exits.

Comment: Can you paste the output of the build which shows stuff like what was installed and what wasn't and what wasn't found, etc. It's like the last 100 or so lines of the make or make install. I don't remember.

Comment: @bad_keypoints http://codepad.org/NGIhw7JW This is the last lines of `make install`. However I don't think this is relevant. I think the problem is about the codec opencv uses. (don't know where to find/change that now)

Comment: @JennyaChang Give the paste of `make`. Make install just tells what binaries/libs it installed and where. Also, please don't put it on codepad.org. I don't know why, but it's banned from my country. I had to see it via a proxy.

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s334/sh/bc7534b6-9196-4515-bb68-4cffa38f8163/ba05619cc642dac72aa4dd88b4feafe2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81605/discussion-between-bad-keypoints-and-jennya-chang).

Comment: You can find the solution here in my previous answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43774606/1170848

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## It's a codec problem

I converted that `mp4` file to an `avi` file with `ffmpeg`. Then the above opencv code can play that `avi` file well.

Therefore I am sure that this is a codec problem.

(I then converted that `mp4` file to another `mp4` file using `ffmpeg`, thinking maybe `ffmpeg` would help turning that original unreadable `.mp4` codec into a readable `.mp4` codec, but the resulting `.mp4` file ended up broken. This fact may or may not relate to this problem, just mentioning, in case anybody needs this information.)

## The answer to it - Rebuild FFmpeg then Rebuild Opencv

Despite knowing this is a codec problem, I tried many other ways but still couldn't solve it. At last I tried rebuilding ffmpeg and opencv, then the problem was solved!

Following is my detailed rebuilding procedure.

**(1) Build ffmpeg**

1. Download ffmpeg-2.7.1.tar.bz2

   > FFmpeg website: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html
   >
   > ffmpeg-2.7.1.tar.bz2 link: http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.7.1.tar.bz2
2. `tar -xvf ffmpeg-2.7.1.tar.bz2`
3. `cd ffmpeg-2.7.1`
4. `./configure --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie`

   > From http://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Advanced-linking-configuration
   >
   > If you compiled FFmpeg libraries statically and you want to use them to build your own shared library, you may need to force PIC support (with `--enable-pic` during FFmpeg configure).
   >
   > If your target platform requires position independent binaries, you should pass the correct linking flag (e.g. `-pie`) to `--extra-ldexeflags`.
   >
   > ---
   >
   > If you encounter error: 
   >   `yasm/nasm not found or too old. Use --disable-yasm for a crippled build.`
   >
   > Just `sudo apt-get install yasm`
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Further building options: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
   >
   > e.g. Adding option `--enable-libmp3lame` enables `png` encoder. (Before `./configure` you need to `sudo apt-get install libmp3lame-dev` with version ≥ 3.98.3)
5. `make -j5` (under ffmpeg folder)
6. `sudo make install`

**(2) Build Opencv**

1. `wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.zip`
2. `unzip opencv-2.4.9.zip`
3. `cd opencv-2.4.9`
4. `mkdir build`
5. `cd build`
6. `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_V4L=ON -D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic ..`

   > You can change those options depend on your needs. Only the last one `-D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic` is the key option. If you omit this one then the `make` will jump out errors.
   >
   > This is also from http://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Advanced-linking-configuration (the same link of step 4 above)
   >
   > If you compiled FFmpeg libraries statically and you want to use them to build your own shared library, you may need to ... and add the following option to your project `LDFLAGS`: `-Wl,-Bsymbolic`
7. `make -j5`
8. `sudo make install`
9. `sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'`
10. `sudo ldconfig`

Now the opencv code should play a `mp4` file well!

## Methods I tried but didn't work

1. Try add `WITH_UNICAP=ON` `WITH_V4L=ON` when `cmake` opencv. But didn't work at all.
2. Try changing codec inside the python opencv code. But in vain.

   > `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("MOV_0006.mp4")`
   >
   > `print cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC)`
   >
   > I tested this in two environment. In the first environment the opencv works, and in the other the opencv fails to play a video. But both printed out same codec `828601953.0`.
   >
   > I tried to change their codec by `cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'H264'))` but didn't work at all.
3. Try changing the libraries under `opencv-2.4.8/3rdparty/lib/` into libraries in my workable environment. But couldn't even successfully build.

   > I grep `AVC: nal size` and find the libraries contain this error message are `opencv-2.4.8/3rdparty/lib/libavcodec.a` etc. That's why I tried to replace them. But it turns out that this is a bad idea.
4. `sudo apt-get -y install libopencv-dev build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config python-dev python-numpy libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev libtbb-dev libqt4-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 v4l-utils unzip`

   > Try to install some that thing and some this thing. But it was totally useless.

## Problems Related

I've searched the web and there are many similar problems, but NONE of them had a solution!

Below are problems I think the same as mine.

- **OpenCV/ffmpeg does not play my mp4 video.** — 
  *from [opencv-users.nabble.com](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/OpenCV-ffmpeg-does-not-play-my-mp4-video-td5697169.html)*
- **VideoCapture is not working in OpenCV 2.4.2** — 
  *from [answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/263/videocapture-is-not-working-in-opencv-242/)*

  > This one mentions rebuilding `ffmpeg`! But the arguments weren't enough for me.
- **Mp4 reading problem - I installed OpenCV 2.4.1 and python 2.7 and made a short program that *reads the avi file successfully*. However it *fails to read mp4 file*.** — 
  *from [answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/9692/mp4-reading/)*
- **Cannot open “.mp4” video files using OpenCV 2.4.3, Python 2.7 in _Windows 7 machine** — 
  *from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834399)*
- **OpenCV 2.4 VideoCapture not working *on Windows*** — 
  *from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows)*

Comment: I followed your exact instructions to rebuild `ffmpeg` and `opencv`, and everything appeared to have went smoothly.  However, my `opencv` is still unable to read `mp4` or `avi` videos.  `import cv2; cv2.VideoCapture('example.mp4').isOpened()` always returns `False`.  My OS is also Ubuntu 14.04.  I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you sure this problem is the same as yours? In this problem, a `.avi` can be opened, while a `.mp4` can't.

Comment: How did you install or configure OpenCV?  I ran a OpenCV 2.4.10 [installation script](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/2.4/opencv2_4_10.sh), and didn't do anything else.

Comment: Originally using the same script as you to install, but then having the codec problem. So then I use the configure step above to reinstall.

Comment: Can you share the ffmpeg command you used to go from .mp4 to .avi? I tried a few but it won't open in opencv, it's missing header info. @AnnieFromTaiwan

Answer (score 2):

for ubuntu 14.04, this is how i fixed it.

**install the dependencies required for OpenCV"**

sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libx264-dev

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-plugins-base libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

sudo apt-get -y install libopencv-dev build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config python-dev python-numpy libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libxine-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev libtbb-dev libqt4-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 v4l-utils unzip

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad

sudo apt-get update

**Install ffmpeg inside anaconda3"**

conda install -c menpo ffmpeg=2.7.0

**Dowload Opencv 3.1.0"**

wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip
unzip 3.1.0.zip

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DENABLE_AVX=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DWITH_IPP=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_EIGEN=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3.5) -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") -DPYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") ..

make

sudo make install

Comment: Dear lord, that's a lot of stuff.  So it works with mp4 files after that?

Comment: Ye it does, I have test it out on Ubuntu 16.10 as well. It works like a charm. You can neglect this part Install ffmpeg inside anaconda3"

conda install -c menpo ffmpeg=2.7.0

Comment: Hi. I follow your steps on ubuntu 16.04, but a lot of package is not found, has no installation candidate : 
E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg'