# Can't show video output from .avi file in Opencv (python)

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video

I can't see any output video window when I run the code.
Python code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\Users\khan1\Desktop\pythonproject\test_1.avi')
print cap
while (cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_green = np.array([65, 60, 60])
    upper_green = np.array([80, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

When I run it I get `Process finished with exit code 0` but it doesn't show any video. If I use `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` for webcam, this code works fine showing 3 different video window. Also `print cap` shows `<VideoCapture 034523B0>`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add double slash in video path

Comment: Add double slash specifically where in the path?

Comment: Change path to C:\\Users\\khan1\\... Or else copy video to project folder and simply pass video name

Comment: Did that. Still same result. `Process finished with exit code 0` and can't see any window. `cv2.imshow` is not showing any window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go over the code provided because this output is what should be expected.

This line is activating your main webcam. If you only have one webcam plugged into your machine then this should be fine.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Next the loop is simply going to capture your webcam's frames until you press the Escape key. You are getting three windows because you are running the imshow function three times:

```
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('res', res)
```

The `frame` variable stores the normal frames via the webcam without modification. The `mask` variable is running a color threshold based on the range of values provided, which in this case is a range between `lower_green` and `upper_green`. The `res` variable is going to display the mask on top of the normal frames hence the bitwise_and operator.

Note that the default color format for opencv is BGR(Blue, Green, Red) and you are converting it to an HSV value, which is why you are probably getting two black screens.

Change the value in your color threshold until you get a better result or try this code which will mask anything not remotely green.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\Users\khan1\Desktop\pythonproject\test_1.avi')
print cap
while (cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    lower_green = np.array([0, 60, 0])
    upper_green = np.array([200, 255, 200])
    mask = cv2.inRange(rgb, lower_green, upper_green)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

You'll notice that in the code provided I am converting it to RGB format not HSV.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this code for me. But my question was why can't I read the video file (test_1.avi) stored on my laptop? Actually I am not seeing any screen. It works fine with webcam, but can't read the video file from the mentioned path. Also BGR2RGB suggestion was also helpful.

Comment: How do I solve that? Is there any known link that I can follow to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040746/cant-open-video-using-opencv

Answer (score 0):

For my 32 bit windows 10 laptop, I copied `opencv_ffmpeg320.dll` from `C:\OpenCV-3.2.0\opencv\build\bin` to `C:\Python27` and that solved the problem. [OpenCV 2.4 VideoCapture not working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699298/opencv-2-4-videocapture-not-working-on-windows) is the link I followed.