# OpenCV cannot read some mp4 files, converting to avi doesn't help either

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to read some video files that have mp4 format using OpenCV python. I didn't have any problem with any other mp4 video that I have used so far, but for some reason, videocapture cannot read these mp4 video files. My problem is not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834399/cannot-open-mp4-video-files-using-opencv-2-4-3-python-2-7-in-windows-7-machi) (I already applied this renaming of mmpeg when I first installed opencv). Besides, as I mentioned earlier videocapture can read other mp4 videos, but not these ones. I also tried to convert the video into avi, but still videocapture cannot read the video (I use other avi files with no problem). The videos that I'm using come from [this dataset](https://cvhci.anthropomatik.kit.edu/~lrybok/projects/kitchen/).

Comment: Can you play the files without a problem with your favorite OS media player?

Comment: Do a rewrap using ffmpeg. `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4`. The H.264 bitstream in the source MP4s is Annex B. That may be the issue.

Comment: @Mulvya rewrapping helped. Thank you!

Comment: @Mulvya Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a rewrap using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4.
```

The H.264 bitstream in the source MP4s is Annex B, which is not expected.

Comment: Since ffmpeg can read, then opencv should be able to read it in a way. This solution resolved the issue I am facing, thanks a lot, but I guess there should be a resolution other than having to do it manually. Thanks dear