# OpenCV cannot open *.mp4 file

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, mp4

I am trying open `*.mp4` file with `opencv`. I am trying with following code but I am unable to do this. How can solve this issue?

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test.mp4")
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test.avi") # it's also not working
cap.isOpened() # Output: False
```

- N.B:

  - OS : ubuntu 16.04
  - OpenCv version: 3.3.0

Comment: take a look [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/9692/mp4-reading/)  most likely you are missing a codec for mp4

Comment: Please check everything listed in the linked answer. If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll reopen the question

Comment: @Miki , I tried to solve this `linked answer` but it doesn't work..

Comment: Please explain why the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112642/permanent-fix-for-opencv-videocapture) doesn't work

Comment: After executing this `ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i avc` I got this ` DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_crystalhd h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )
 D.A.L. avc                  On2 Audio for Video Codec (decoders: on2avc )
`

Comment: python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i ffmpeg

FFMPEG:                      NO

Comment: _"If the output is No then follow an online guide to build OpenCV from source with ffmpeg support."_

Comment: @Miki Where I will get `online guide to build OpenCV` ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this post up-to-date. However, I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.4 and had installed the opencv via conda:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

And it turned out that menpo is not supported anymore. After installing from conda-forge, the problem disappeared:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

You can surely check if the mpeg support is there:

```
python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i ffmpeg
```

it should return "YES"

Answer (score 2):

install this package, it enable ffmpeg in opencv:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 1):

Install this package

> pip install VideoCapture

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test.mp4")
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test.avi")
cap.isOpened() 

cap.release()
```

Answer (score -1):

try updating opencv.
also, this might help: [Cannot open ".mp4" video files using OpenCV 2.4.3, Python 2.7 in Windows 7 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834399/cannot-open-mp4-video-files-using-opencv-2-4-3-python-2-7-in-windows-7-machi)